# Monitor devices network usage and bandwidth in real time

Tags: networking, hot-spot

I want to make a hotspot connection from my PC running any linux distribution by sharing the network connection from my ethernet port and redirect network to all other devices in the network. I need to do this to monitor the internet consumption(GBs) used by each separate device and the bandwidth it uses in real time and to know which websites use this internet. I know this could be implemented by a installing custom firmware in the router, but this option is not really available for now. Making the hotspot part isn't the problem, but is there any software that can do the above features(monitor usage and bandwidth used by each device and the websites that used it)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor the network traffic.

Comment: Wireshark is not really the best option I only want the data used by each device not each packet and besides, does it even have the option to view all used data or do I have to sum up all the individual packets?

Comment: unter 'Statistics>IO Graph' you could plot things like traffic. But you are right it's kind of a overkill option. Besides monitoring multiple interfaces could be a problem.